# Coral Dev Board Mini i2C connect to Adafruit Motor Shield V2

Tags: i2c, adafruit, google-coral, motordriver

Anyone have any success connecting the Coral Dev Board Mini to Adafruit's Motor Shield V2 (AMS) with I2C?

My first solution was to use the only 3 PWM on the Dev Mini to control the speed and direction of a motor, but i need two motors.

So decided to go the I2C route coupled with Adafruit's Motor Shield V2.

I've connected the following pins between the board and shield

```
Mini 5V -> AMS Vin
Mini GND -> AMS GND
Mini SDA (pin 3) -> AMS SDA pin
Mini SCL (pin 5) -> AMS SCL pin
```

On the mini the SDA/SCL pins 3 & 5 are associated with device path /dev/i2c-3

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 3
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

and I should be seeing 0x60.

The default Mini pin states are

```
HIGH (4.7K pull-up)
```

Any ideas?

Or Any thoughts on another solution to control the speed and direction of two motors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Adadfruit motor driver, but if you connect +5V to it's Vin it might well pull up the I2C lines to this voltage which might not be compatible with the 3.3V the mini dev uses. Have you checked this?

I have tried something similar, but with the SparkFun Auto pHAT (which does 3.3V <-> 5V conversion on the I2C bus). I could not get I2C working between the Auto pHat and the dev board mini. Maybe something in the I2C implementation of the mini is not working out of the box. I could control the Auto pHat with a (3.3V) ESP32 without problems.

I have also developed my own motor driver which is controlled by I2C and the prototype works well with the ESP32, I have not yet tried it with the the dev board mini. I'll give it a try and let you know.